# Resignalling exceptions unless they are of a certain type

Tags: error-handling, smalltalk, visualworks

I want to make sure that evaluating aBlock only raises errors of type SomeCustomError. Is there a better way than using isKindOf: ?

```
aBlock 
  on: Core.Error
  do: [:ex | 
       (ex isKindOf: SomeCustomError) 
         ifTrue: [ex pass]
         ifFalse: [(SomeCustomError identification: #generalError messageText: ex messageText) raise]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach - define method **isMyTerribleException** at class **Exception** and it should return **false**. At your **CustomException** class define redefine method with returning **true**

```
aBlock 
  on: Core.Error
  do: [:ex | 
       (ex isMyTerribleException) 
         ifTrue: [ex pass]
         ifFalse: [(SomeCustomError identification: #generalError messageText: ex     messageText) raise]]
```

It would be better, because you can are introducing new Exception classes, which must be catched

Answer (score 1):

This sounds strange to me. Two things

**1) HOW:**

You are resignalling from the handler context.
Is it really what you want?
Or do you want to resignal from original context where first error was raised?

In the latter case you should use something like:

```
ex resignalAs: (SomeCustomError identification: #generalError messageText: ex messageText)
```

**2) WHAT:**

It's not isKindOf: which bothers me, but the whole idea...
Catch all kind of Error and replace by specific one?
What is the use case?
Who will catch the specific one?
Or does the specific one has a different default action?

Comment: This code is used inside an importer class where I would like the import functionality to only throw SomeCustomError when importing goes wrong. But #validate: on XML.Schema
sometimes throws plain Error exceptions.